# Xcode CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I don't know why I get this, when I build a iPad project in xcode4.6. 
iOS sdk 6.1, simulator 6.1.

`/Applications/Xcode4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:92:10: 'CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found
In file included from /Applications/Xcode4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:5:10`

Comment: Just a small heads up, if you plan to submit your app to the AppStore you need to build it with the iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for you reply, it can build successfully. But this project requires the ios SDK 6.1 :(

Comment: Apple only accepts new AppStore apps build with Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK. You are no longer able to submit update or new apps build with the iOS 6 SDK. You will need to upgrade Xcode and change your app to support iOS 7. You can of course still set the deployment target to iOS 6.