# Xcode 7 "CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h" file not found

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I am porting [MobileTerminal](https://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/source/checkout) to iOS. I am getting this error from Xcode 7 iOS SDK 9.0. [Here](https://github.com/hughkf/ios-term) is my Git repo. Here is the full error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:92:10: 'CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found
```

Followed by this context:

```
/Users/user1/Documents/DEV/ios-term/Classes/Terminal/TerminalGroupView.mm:4:9: In file included from /Users/user1/Documents/DEV/ios-term/Classes/Terminal/TerminalGroupView.mm:4:
/Users/user1/Documents/DEV/ios-term/Classes/Terminal/TerminalGroupView.h:4:9: In file included from /Users/user1/Documents/DEV/ios-term/Classes/Terminal/TerminalGroupView.h:4:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:9: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:9: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
```

This question was opened [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830156/xcode-corefoundation-cfusernotification-h-file-not-found), but the actual error was not solved.